# Why first node or single node only register in Rancher 2 server + Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rancher, rke

I have the following things are running on `OracleVmBox`. My host is window-10.

```
192.168.88.90   CentOs 7    Rancher     docker-version is 17.03.2
192.168.88.108  CentOs 7    Node-1      docker-version is 17.03.2
192.168.88.112  CentOs 7    Node-2      docker-version is 17.03.2
192.168.88.113  CentOs 7    Node-3      docker-version is 17.03.2
```

I already install `Rancher sever` on `192.168.88.90` and I create a new cluster.

[image]

And, I run the following commend in all node.

```
docker run -d --privileged --restart=unless-stopped --net=host -v /etc/kubernetes:/etc/kubernetes \ 
-v /var/run:/var/run rancher/rancher-agent:v2.1.5 --server https://192.168.88.90 \ 
--token vsfvjnbsggrkjd5vmnbmddn4q6jhsqtfhzj44wxb7cc92q87r9cjkc \
--ca-checksum 87d755c7c304dc3c2cdbca307aef4874ed3d17789da62826c0aa812bd10d3cf9 \ 
--etcd --controlplane --worker
```

The problems is, only first node(`192.168.88.108`) is register/add in cluster because of I run above commend in `192.168.88.108` **at first** and Node-2 and Node-3 and so on.
Node-2 and Node-3 are not registed/add into the cluster.

**Update**
[image]

Comment: Did you check the network settings of the VM software? Also are the non working CentOS machines configured identically to the first one? Any firewall rules which could be preventing the communication? What do the logs in the agent container point to?

Comment: First one and the rest of Vm are same because of I cone all thing in VmBox. 
Thank for your help.

Comment: Any communication errors in the `rancher-agent` logs?

Answer (score 0):

if you have 3 machine on virtualbox. you create 3 cluster.

example;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9uYL.png)
have a good day.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.